# Unity3D Unsafe code requires the `unsafe' command line option to be specified

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, unsafe

i am using `Unity3D 4.3` and calling a `DLL` that i created.
when trying to call the only function it have which is this:

```
void GetModelReferences(int &nVertices, float * vertices, int &nTriangles, int * triangles, float * normals, float * uvCoordinates);
```

unity gives me an error:

```
Unsafe code requires the `unsafe' command line option to be specified
```

so in my `MonoDevelop` i opened : `Project->Assembly-Csharp options` and turned on the `unsafe` mode.

it reduces part of the errors but this last one wont go away

```
Unsafe code requires the `unsafe' command line option to be specified
```

what shoud i do?

Comment: Do you have more than one project? May be that you need to check that setting on more than one project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to your project properties page and check under `Build` the checkbox `Allow unsafe code`.
This should solve your problem.

Comment: the unsafe code is in the c# script that attached to an object in unity, what then?

Comment: Is the unity project a C# project? If so, there is also a property page for this. If not, I simply not know, how unity is executing the script.

Comment: ok, i know i need to add the option\flag but i dont know how to get there

Comment: In MonoDevelop: menu Project/Assembly-CSharp Options then Build/General/ Allow unsafe

Answer (score 8):

Here is what worked for me with Unity3D 5.3:
- If in your Unity Build Setting->Player Setting->Other Settings, "API Compatibility Level" is ".Net 2.0", create a file under your Unity Asset folder called gmcs.rsp, add this following line to the file:
-unsafe
Close Unity and open it again.
- If the  "API Compatibility Level" is ".Net 2.0 Subset", the above file name should be: smcs.rsp.

See the picture bellow to find the location of ""API Compatibility Level" setting in Unity.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The answer is given here: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/804103/how-to-enable-unsafe-and-use-pointers.html

You need to add a file "smcs.rsp" (or "gmcs.rsp") in your "Assets" directory, which contains the line:

```
-unsafe
```

Comment: This was the only usefull answer for me. Since I can not use `.NET 2.0 Subset` and my Unity Project Settings do not have the option to *allow* unsafe code.

Comment: when targeting the .NET 3.5 Equivalent (deprecated) scripting runtime version, mcs is used with mcs.rsp, and
when targeting the .NET 4.x Eqivalent scripting runtime version compiler, csc is used with csc.rsp.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unsafe-code-in-unity.7009/) ?

look at the fifth comment

> Firstly show the contents of Unity.App and drill down to Contents/Frameworks/MonoCompiler.framework.
>
> Open the file called compile_any.pl and in the section "# Run the
>   csharp compiler" change @Base_Args options as below:
>
> my @base_args=($mono_path, $mcs_path, '-debug', '-unsafe', '-target:library', '-nowarn:0169', '-out:'.$output,  );

Comment: i am running from a pc

Comment: Miloš Selečéni, which version of Unity is this for?  Mine has a Frameworks folder, but no MonoCompiler.framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the settings through the MonoDevelop:
go to the solution files tree -> 
Solution -> your expand your solution -> Assempely-CSharp -> Right Click -> options -> Build -> General -> Language options -> enable "Allow 'unsafe' code"

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a unity project, open Project Settings>Other Settings>Allow Unsafe Code