# sizeof custom struct for compute shader stride

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a compute shader with Unity that generates mesh data (vertices, normals, uvs) for a voxel terrain. Thus, I have a custom struct defined as follows :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
private struct VertexData
{
    public Vector3 position;

    public Vector3 normal;

    public Vector2 uv;
}
```

Then, I'm creating a ComputeBuffer for the ComputeShader as follows :

```
vecterDataCBuf = new ComputeBuffer(ChunkSize * ChunkSize * ChunkSize, sizeof(VertexData));
```

I'm getting the CS0233 error indicating the I can't use the sizeof operator on my custom struct to provide the stride for the compute buffer, despite the packing attribute I added.

So my question is, how can I get the size of my struct without hard coding it ? Thank you.

Comment: I believe unity has a specific helper method for this: `UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T>()`. Either that or you'll have to compile with the unsafe flag to use the sizeof operator.

Comment: @mikez That [seems to be correct](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.UnsafeUtility.SizeOf.html). Shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am hardly an expert in unity, so that may not be the correct method. I found it relatively quickly with google, but looking through the example code in their github repo they almost always use sizeof or System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf.

Comment: Interesting to know ! Thanks.

Comment: I ran into this and I'm using `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` and `public static int SizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStructType));` inside my structs as well. 

It's working in editor, have not tried a build yet. I'm also not getting unsafe warnings. It does seem a little overkill though considering that I can caluclate it manually, but it's very handy for dev when I'm actively changing the structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` only works for predefined types unless you're in an `unsafe` context. [From the reference on `sizeof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sizeof):

> The following table shows the constant values that are substituted for sizeof expressions that have certain built-in types as operands. [...] For all other types, including structs, the sizeof operator can be used only in unsafe code blocks.

So wrap your call in `unsafe` like:

```
int sizeOfVertexData;
unsafe
{
    sizeOfVertexData = sizeof(VertexData);
}
```

You'll also have to enable unsafe code. [In Unity it's apparently a checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512920/2137382).

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how is it making the code unsafe ? The size can differ between platforms / compilers / hardwares ? I'm assuming the unsafe keyword is required for a good reason.

Comment: @Virus721 The link to the documentation on this answers point [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/index). I would suggest you get familiar with that

Comment: @Virus721 For ordinary C# apps the most common uses of `sizeof` involve pointers or reading/writing memory. Normally, C#/.NET manages memory for you, preventing many kinds of security holes, but pointer operations bypass some of this protection. The code is called `unsafe` not because it's necessarily dangerous, but because it *could be* dangerous (intentionally or unintentionally through bugs). However, for this context, given you're just using `sizeof`, it's probably fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the total size of your struct by adding each property size.

A Vector3 is equivalent to 3 floats.
A Vector2 is equivalent to 2 floats.

```
//int stride  = sizeof(position) + sizeof(normal) + sizeof(uv)
//int stride  = sizeof(Vector3) + sizeof(Vector3) + sizeof(Vector2)
int stride = sizeof(float) * 3 + sizeof(float) * 3 + sizeof(float) * 2
```

You don't need unsafe stuff.

Comment: This, especially with the formatting shortcomings, is borderline code-only. Please extend your explanation and use this to help recognising that ther IS in fact something of an explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: this matched my results using method below, im here because I made an error elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Also there is another way:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //....

Marshal.SizeOf(new CustomData())
```